# iOS Why I can't log in facebook app by parse Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have issues with log in facebook, in https://developers.facebook.com/ all information only for OBJC, but i work with swift.

My code to log in:

```
let permissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(withReadPermissions: permissions) { (user, error) in

        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
            } else {
                print("User logged in through Facebook!")
            }
        } else {
            print("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
}
```

If i add information in browser ,it will work.But if I want to log in FACEBOOK app, it' will not work.

I really tired to search information to fix.

Comment: here it is in swift [Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login)

Comment: @Ketan Odedra yes, this information i found in network